# How to running logstash on background as a services

Tags: logstash

I have logstash configuration and running well when I running this on terminal

`/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/receiver.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash`

The problem is, I want to logstash running on background as a service. But its not work when I tried to running with

`systemctl start logstash`

**This is configuration on my /etc/logstash/logstash.yml**

```
path.data: /var/lib/test

path.config: /etc/logstash/conf.d/receiver.conf

path.logs: /var/log/logstash
```

**This is configuration on my /etc/logstash/pipeline.yml**

```
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"
```

I'm using Linux 10 to running this logstash. Is there any changes I have to do with the services or I missing something?

Comment: What do you have in your logs? Also, I don't think you can use `path.config` in `logstash.yml` if you are going to use `piplines.yml`, if you are going to run logstash as a service, put your configurations in `pipelines.yml`.

Comment: @leandrojmp thankyou for your reply. Logstash-plain.log shows nothing, also my configuration not running because no logs comes into my output. Oh, okay noted,  I was trying to solve the issue with that in hope it can works.